# Explanation behind this (working) query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `Clients` and `Contacts` (see below), and wanted to fetch all clients, with only their last added contact.

I was almost considering using a subquery because I couldn't use `LIMIT 1` on my joined contacts, until I stumbled upon this solution, which seems to be very simple.

Problem is, I don't really understand what it's doing. The logic behind the `WHERE` clause is also beyond me.

Side-question to this: Are two joins still faster than a subquery?

PS: I'm using MySQL.

Thanks.

```
SELECT
    cl.clientId as clientId,
    cl.clientName as clientName,
    c1.firstName as firstName,
    c1.lastName as lastName,
    c1.added as added
FROM Clients as cl
LEFT JOIN Contacts as c1 ON cl.clientId = c1.clientId
LEFT JOIN Contacts as c2 ON cl.clientId = c2.clientId AND c1.added < c2.added
WHERE c2.added IS NULL
```

Clients

```
-----------------------------
 clientId     clientName
-----------------------------
    1          Johnny's
    2          Bonnie's
```

Contacts

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 clientId     firstName     lastName        added
-------------------------------------------------------
    1          Johnny        Simmons      2013-06-17
    1          Jane          Simmons      2013-06-18
    2          Bonnie        Hall         2013-06-19
```

Result

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 clientId     clientName     firstName     lastName        added
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1          Johnny's       Jane          Simmons      2013-06-18
    2          Bonnie's       Bonnie        Hall         2013-06-19
```

Comment: How does one *stumble* onto this solution?

Comment: It's simple: this clause 'c1.added < c2.added' means that in c2 will always be values with the later dates. So, if c2 is null, that means there is no latest values for this client, so this is the latest one.

Comment: Mikhail: I think you'll find that is an answer and not a comment. ;-)

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: @Jakub: I don't think any of that SQL is implementation specific is it?

Comment: It's basically this very answer [right here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7485965/2187401), but it seemed a bit dated to ask an explanation there.

Comment: @Chris the side-question is very db specific (not to mention the subquery could be correlated or not).

Comment: @JakubKania I'm using MySQL. (post updated)

Comment: @JakubKania: Ooops, didn't notice that. Maybe my SO mind just filters out any secondary questions. ;-)

Comment: There is nothing DBMS specific to this code. It should work everywhere.

Comment: I suspect the more important question for the side question is to see the SQL of the intended solution with subqueries. :)

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately, I didn't have a solution yet, which uses a subquery. :)

Comment: @jlmmns Well, there is a thing about mysql and left-joins - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072875/awful-mysql-left-join-performance-for-groupwise-maximum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN Contacts as c2 ON cl.clientId = c2.clientId AND c1.added < c2.added
WHERE c2.added IS NULL
```

The `where` clause says: there cannot be a row in `Contacts` that matches `cl.clientId = c2.clientId AND c1.added < c2.added`.  That filters out all contacts for which another contact exists that was added earlier.

So you end up with the latest contact per customer.

Answer (score 1):

THE `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE NULL` is equivalent to this `NOT EXISTS()` query. Performance may differ between platforms (one would expect the same query plan for both versions)
Mysql folks seem to prefer a `max(added)` subquery.

```
SELECT
    cl.clientId as clientId,
    cl.clientName as clientName,
    c1.firstName as firstName,
    c1.lastName as lastName,
    c1.added as added
FROM Clients as cl
LEFT JOIN Contacts as c1 ON cl.clientId = c1.clientId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM Contacts as c2 
  WHERE cl.clientId = c2.clientId
    AND c1.added < c2.added
  );
```

The explanation is the same as for @Andomar 's answer, if c1.added is the maximal value (for this client_id), then there cannot exist another record with a higher value (for this client_id)