# oracle sql 2 records per day per unique fields, how to get the latest

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the table structure:

```
ID
FIELD_A
FIELD_B
DATE_FIELD
VALUE_FIELD
```

The ID field is just a number that increments with each record. We get 2 "sets" of records in a day where FIELD_A, FIELD_B, DATE_FIELD are exactly the same but the VALUE_FIELD can be different. We get a morning set and an evening set. You can tell which is which because of the ID value being lower for that set of records for the morning set (because they were inserted first) and the ID being higher for the evening records (because they were inserted after) in that set.

The question is, if I want to have a view that looks at the highest ID value for FIELD_A, FIELD_B, DATE_FIELD for every record how would I do that? Basically I don't care about the morning sets in my view for anything and only want to see the evening. However, on the current day if we are still in the morning the "highest" ID value will be the only ID value at that time and so a max(id) will give me what we have for current day in the morning at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the analytic function `row_number()`:

```
create view vw_afternoon as
    select id, field_a, field_b, date_field, value_field
    from (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by field_a, field_b, date_field
                                    order by id desc
                                   ) as seqnum
          from t
         ) t
    where seqnum = 1;
```

The function `row_number()` assigns a sequential value to rows within a group (defined by the `partition` clause).  The one with the highest id gets a value of `1`, followed by the rest (as defined by the `order by` clause).

Comment: Very nice. Thank you! I was able to translate this to my specific situation and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs an answer that works in SQL environments that don't support partition_by, I think you can also use:

```
create view my_view as SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN
   (SELECT max(id) FROM my_table GROUP BY field_a, field_b, date_field)
```

Comment: I tried to do this but in my situation this was dog slow. This table has 124+ million records. The solution I accepted was basically instant for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, kind of reminded me of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199505/explanation-behind-this-working-query) question :). Something like that should work:

```
    CREATE VIEW afternoon AS
    SELECT t1.* FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2 
    ON t1.field_a = t2.field_a AND t1.field_b = t2.field_b 
    AND t1.date_field = t2.date_field AND t1.id > t2.id
```